# Finding the lowest common ancestor (LCA) in neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I need to find the LCA for a database in neo4j using either a cypher query or a python client library such as pye2neo.

I'm aware of algorithms to do this e.g. [here](http://bio4j.com/blog/2012/02/finding-the-lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-set-of-ncbi-taxonomy-nodes-with-bio4j/). But before I implement an algorithm myself in python, I want to know if there is a built-in method for this or some other pre-existing package.

At the moment my method consists of:

```
Query = 'match p1 = (con1) -[*0..]-> (common) <-[*0..]- (con2) 
where con1.name = A and con2.name = B 
return common, p1'
```

for starting nodes A and B

1. Execute the query for any two starting nodes. This returns the common ancestor and its path.
2. For each of the remaining nodes in the query (e.g. C,D,E...), execute the query for that node and the previously returned parent. This parent replaces the previous one.
3. The last parent found is the LCA

Psuedo code:

```
input_nodes = [A, B, C, D, E]

parent = get_common(input_nodes[0], input_nodes[1])
for node in input_nodes[2:]:
    parent = get_common(parent, node)
```

In summary: Is there a simple in-built/pre-existing way of finding the LCA from a variable number of input nodes using either a python client library or cypher?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. What do you mean by "remaining nodes in the query"?

It sounds like a modified version of ShortestPath would be useful. It is bidirectional and by default it searches in the reversed direction from the end node. If both sides where to use the same direction (say outgoing) then you would reach the lowest common ancestor (at least as far as I understod your question).